# How to get the specific ads from Adview for coding?

Tags: admob

I am using AdMob in my application. The way to use AdMob for me is not only display ads in my application but also to know what exactly ad is displayed through the code. How to get the content of the AdView in the code so that I know what ad is displayed in real time? Does AdMob provide these kind APIs? I have been searching it but haven't found answer yet.

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt there is any simple way of doing this. Out of curiosity, why do you want this? What will you use this information for?

Comment: I am not curious of the ads from Admob. I have a few my own ads added as house ads in my Admob account. Need to access those contents when they are coming in real time.

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes more sense. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unless you're using DoubleClick for Publishers with the AdMob SDK, there is no way using AdMob APIs to get the creative content at this time.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at DoubleClick then.